# First char omitted by simple programm

Tags: c++, cin

The task is to `cin>>....`, take only letters, change upper case letters to lower case and rewrite line with only lower case letters. I cannot figure out why my code is ignoring the first letter entered.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char ch;
    cin >> ch;
    while (ch != '@'){
        if (cin.get(ch))
        {
            if (isalpha(ch)){
                if (isupper(ch)){
                    cout <<(char)tolower(ch);

                }
                else
                    cout << ch;
            }
            if (ch == '\n')
                cout << "\nNie zakonczyles ciagu znakiem @" << endl;

        }
        else{
            cin.clear();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the loop uses `cin.get(ch)` to get the character to print, but the first character is actually read with `cin >> ch`; and then the result is discarded.

You might want to get rid of the `cin>>ch;` instruction and initialize `ch` to a value different from `'@'`, or transform the loop into a `do-while` loop, similar to this:

```
char ch;
do
{
    if (cin.get(ch))
    {
       /* Do what is needed */
    }
}
while (ch != '@')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
cin >> ch;  <- read first letter
while (ch != '@'){
    if (cin.get(ch)) <- read next letter which tosses out the first letter
```

To fix this set `ch` to some value and then get rid of `cin >> ch;`

Answer (score 2):

Because just after `cin >> ch;` you're doing `cin.get(ch)`.